# i have no idea how to add collision to the paddles for my altered pong code

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a 4 man pong on all sides of the square but am blanking on how to add collision between each individual paddle so they don't phase into each other on the corners

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
### Colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("GNOP")

x = 485
y = 75
x2 = 5
y2 = 75
x3 = 250
y3 = 5
y4 = 485
x4 = 250
width = 10
height = 90
vel = 5

run = True
while run:
    print(x4,y4)
    pygame.time.delay(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    key= pygame.key.get_pressed() 
    if key [pygame.K_UP] and y>0:
        y -= vel
    if key [pygame.K_DOWN]and y<420:
        y += vel
    if key [pygame.K_w] and y2>0:
        y2 -= vel
    if key [pygame.K_s]and y2<420:
        y2 += vel
    if key [pygame.K_c] and x3>0:
        x3 -= vel
    if key [pygame.K_v] and x3<420:
        print(1)
        x3 += vel
    if key [pygame.K_n] and x4>0:
        x4 -= vel
    if key [pygame.K_m] and x4<420:
        x4 += vel

def ball (self):
    # Create the image of the ball
    self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 10]) 
    # Color the ball
    self.image.fill(BLACK)

    # Get a rectangle object that shows where our image is
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    # Get attributes for the height/width of the screen
    self.screenheight = pygame.display.get_surface().get_height()
    self.screenwidth = pygame.display.get_surface().get_width()

    # Speed in pixels per cycle
    self.speed = 0

    # Floating point representation of where the ball is
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0

    # Direction of ball in degrees
    self.direction = 0

    # Height and width of the ball
    self.width = 10
    self.height = 10

    # Set the initial ball speed and position
    self.reset()

win.fill((230,230,230))
pygame.draw.rect(win,(0, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,50,0), (x2, y2, width, height))
pygame.draw.rect(win,(150,15,200), (x3, y3, height, width))
pygame.draw.rect(win,(0,100,255), (x4, y4, height, width))
pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
ball()
```

I need the paddles to detect each other and collide instead of phase into one another but I have watched several codes and I have yet to learn how to do that for each one individually, this is crucial because i can not get the ball to work without it

Comment: ...which is to say -- a question should have only the *shortest possible* code that reproduces a specific, narrow bug. An ideal question is going to be helpful to anyone else with the same problem -- which means it needs to be *about* a specific, isolated problem; not just one person's individual code.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to detect collision:

```
def touched(tar_x,tar_y,tarimage,tar_x1,tar_y1,tarimage2):
    for i in range(tar_x1,tar_x1 + tarimage2.get_width()):
        for j in range(tar_y1,tar_y1 + tarimage2.get_height()):
            if tar_x < i < tar_x + tarimage.get_width() and tar_y < j < tar_y + tarimage.get_height():
                return True
    return False
```

tar_x,tar_y is the position of the first object
tar_x1,tar_y1 is the position of the second object
tarimage, tarimage2 is the image loaded into pygame